# Show terminal window from systemd service daemon

Tags: linux, shell-script, systemd, raspbian, lxterminal

**Setup:**

- Raspberry Pi running raspbian with a display connected (HDMI)
- A continuously running systemd service (daemon)

**Goal:**

- Starting a new terminal window that's visible on the display
- As a proof of concept I would like to run a shell script

Running the shell script within the service works without problem but opening a visible window on the display seems to be hard.

**The code (daemon)**

```
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{Paths.Dotnet} /path/to/app.dll\"",
                WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

** **EDIT** **
Modyfying the arguments to:

```
Arguments = $"-c \"DISPLAY=:0.0 lxterminal -e {Paths.Dotnet} /path/to/app.dll\""
```

Didn't fix the issue. app.dll is executed but still in the background.

Comment: Do you connect a display with HDMI cable or GPIO pins?

Comment: It's connected with an HDMI cable

Comment: IIUC, you can simply connect to the running RPI by ssh and show a terminal window with running command like that: `DISPLAY=:0.0 lxterminal -e ./RUN.sh`.

Comment: Can you post contents of systemd service and describe how you start it?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes indeed that works, Thanks!. At least with ssh. Now i'll try within the service. Before I have tried the same without the -e command. I'll post some code shortly (dotnet though)